# Click on Div to get information box for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below:
And what I need to do is to be able to click on the Div right below and when done the #info_page div would show up in the middle of the screen for a few seconds. Like a dialog but just a simple jquery temp show() with a timer?
Is this possible?

The current code is below.

```
<div onclick="show_info_box">Click to get message</div>


<div id="info_box" style="display:none">
<span class="custom info">
<img src="info.png" alt="info" height="48" width="48" />
<em>Information</em>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you have so far for the `show_info_box()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and its dialog to do this, set a timeout once the dialog has been opened to close it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#info_box").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        open: function() {
            // close the dialog 10 secs after it's opened
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }, 10000);
        }
    });

    // you'll need to set an ID on the DIV that you click
    $("#DIVID").bind("click", function() {
        $("#info_box").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change show_info_box to show_info_box(), in the onclick code, and here's the function...

```
function show_info_box() {
    $("#info_box").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#info_box").hide();
    }, 5000);
}
```

You can change the show and hide for fadeIn() and fadeOut() for a nicer look, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
function show_info_box() {
   //Get info_box
   var info = $('div#info_box');
   //Fade the box in during 1 sec, show it for 5, and let it fade out again
   info.fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

I made you a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v5UdP/

Note though that you wrote `onclick="show_info_box"` where it should say `onclick="show_info_box()"`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're using inline events (`onclick=""`) just in this example code here and not in production, but anyways..

```
function show_info_box() {
    var info_box = $('#info_box');
    info_box.show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        info_box.hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

The centering of the box should be done via CSS. Just put a `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;` wrapper around the box and give the box a `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.show_msg').bind('click', function(e) {
    //Stores overlay element
    var overlay = $("#info_box");
    //Position element in the center of the screen
    overlay.offset({'top': Math.ceil($(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() - overlay.outerHeight())/2),'left': Math.ceil(($(window).width() - overlay.outerWidth())/2)});
    //Show the overlay for 2 seconds
    overlay.fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Here is a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/WLYDe/1/. Positioning center, but not using the dialog plugin.